# What does the loss calculation from spacy textcat tells me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, text-classification

I am new to NLP and use of spacy. What does the 'loss' in spacy textcat mean? I get value of 0.0000 for all iterations during constructing a custom text classifier using spacy textcat model training. I'm wondering if there is some problem with my model training.

```
        for i in range(n_iter):
            losses = {}
            # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
            batches = minibatch(train_data, size=compounding(4., 32., 1.001))
            for batch in batches:
                texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
                #print('texts: '+str(texts))
                #print('annotations: '+str(annotations))
                nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.2,losses=losses)
            # with textcat.model.use_params(optimizer.averages):
                # evaluate on the dev data split off in load_data()

            print('{0:.3f}'  # print a simple table
                  .format(losses['textcat']))
```

What does the code below on output_dir mean?

```
    if output_dir is not None:
        output_dir = Path(output_dir)
        if not output_dir.exists():
            output_dir.mkdir()
        nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
        print("Saved model to", output_dir)

        # test the saved model
        print("Loading from", output_dir)
        nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
        doc2 = nlp2(test_text)
        print(test_text, doc2.cats)
```

Comment: From [the doc](https://spacy.io/api/pipe#update) the `nlp.update` functions returns a loss dictionary, have you tried that instead of passing the `losses` parameter ? And the code about the `output_dir` created a directory if it does not exist, and save the model. I don't if this is the answer you expected ?

Answer (score 1):

How higher your loss, how less accurate the model is.
A 0.00000x loss means the model is 100% accurate

Your code could be wrong. I suggest maybe checking on [phind](https://phind.com) and ask it if it could be wrong. I'm not on a machine currently able to do machine learning due to recent broken PC..